# Template argument deduction/substitution failed with gcc 5.2, ok with gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have problem with the following code (minified example):

```
#include <stdint.h>

class Color {
public:
        Color (uint32_t r=0, uint32_t g=0, uint32_t b=0)
                :r(r), g(g), b(b) {}
        ~Color ()=default;
private:
        uint8_t r;
        uint8_t g;
        uint8_t b;
};

template<const Color &color>
struct text_descriptor_clr {
        int                     id;
        uint32_t                font;
        const char              *label;
};

class Text {
public:
        template<const Color &use_color>
        void create (const text_descriptor_clr<use_color> &d)
        {
                font=d.font;
        }
        uint32_t font;
};

extern const Color WHITE;
const Color WHITE(255,255,255);

int main()
{
        Text t1;
        text_descriptor_clr<WHITE> d;
        t1.create(d);
}
```

It compiles with no error with gcc 4.8.2:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
...

g++ -o gcctest gcctest.cpp -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
(no errors)
```

But fails, when compiled with gcc 5.2.0:

```
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.2.0
...

g++ -o gcctest  gcctest.cpp  -std=c++0x
gcctest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
gcctest.cpp:38:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘Text::create(text_descriptor_clr<WHITE>&)’
  t1.create(d);
             ^
gcctest.cpp:24:7: note: candidate: template<const Color& use_color> void Text::create(const text_descriptor_clr<use_color>&)
  void create (const text_descriptor_clr<use_color> &d)
       ^
gcctest.cpp:24:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
gcctest.cpp:38:13: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘use_color’
  t1.create(d);
```

The most suspicious part in this code is that I'm using template with class instance as parameter, I couldn't find information that it is allowed. Not a type, not an int, but instance of Color class. With gcc 4.8.2 it works as expected.

However, the real problem is template parameter deduction (if I remove the last line from the function, it compiles with gcc 5.2.0)

What is the reason for the different behavior? Which gcc is right here?

Comment: I would add `-Wall and -Wextra` to compiling options. It should fail, with can't deduce template argument.

Comment: clang gives *"note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure : deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the its corresponding template parameter ('Color' vs 'const Color &')"* for `void create (const text_descriptor_clr<use_color> &d)`

Comment: As a workaround, you may use `template<const Color *color>`